# How set C++ class to an Item in qml?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a c++ class with name `Class2` and I registered it with `qmlRegisterType` method and I use it as code behind of qml pages in my application.

I have qml file and in `onCompleted` I want to get an object of `Class2` and set it to `cl2` in the qml file .but I get an error

> left-hand side of assignment operator is not an lvalue

```
Rectangle{
    Component.onCompleted: {
        cl2=ObjectAccessor.class2obj;//error is here
    }
    Class2 {
            id: cl2
            onMessageChanged: { }                
    }
}
```

In qml file I changed the defenition of `Class2`

```
property Class2 cl2: Class2 {}
```

but now i get another error

> Cannot assign [undefined] to Class2*

How can i set object of `Class2' so i can all data on this object an all signals?

Comment: What is Class2? Where have you defined it? what is ObjectAccessor? you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc Class2 is an c++ class that i used for code behind of qml pages in my app.for get some data from network and so on...

Comment: I think you know from your reputation that for these cases the most appropriate thing is to provide a [mcve], the error can be found elsewhere.

Comment: Why are you assigning a new object to the object? I think you're trying to make a fool of yourself, without context I do not understand what you're trying.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why c++ signal will not work after use class as property in qml page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024891/why-c-signal-will-not-work-after-use-class-as-property-in-qml-page)

Comment: this new object have some information in himself.for exmaple data that receveid it form network.and i have set this object from another qml file to object accessor and in this qml file i get it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all `class2obj` being `undefined` means it is not property interfaced to be accessible from QML.

Second, you cannot assign a qml object to another qml object. It depends on what you want to do.

If you want to assign identity, you will have to put it into a target reference, implemented as a property:

```
property Class2 cl2: null
...
cl2=ObjectAccessor.class2obj
```

If you want to assign value, as in to make the property values of the one object to the other, you will have to that member by member.

And if all you need is to connect to a signal, then all you need is a connection element, provided that `ObjectAccessor.class2obj` actually works:

```
Connections {
  target: ObjectAccessor.class2obj
  onMessageChanged: doStuff()
}
```

For a more complete answer, you will have to post the code related to `Class2` and `ObjectAccessor`. And also clarify that bit:

> so i can all data on this object an all signals

Comment: `property Class2 cl2: null` ok If i use like this.How can i use signals of Class2?for example `onMessagedChanged`?

Comment: Refresh the answer - the Connection element is what you need and you don't really need the property part.